# R using groupby to add rows to dataframe

Tags: r

New R user here. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
│   │ uID │ day│ status │
├───┼─────┼────┼────────┤
│   │ A   │ 5  │ 1      │
│   │ B   │ 4  │ 1      │
│   │ C   │ 9  │ 1      │
```

I want to add new rows to this table so that each uID has a row for all days from 1 to [[day]]. Additionally, for all days leading up to [[day]], each uID's status will be 0.

For example:

```
│   │ uID │ day │ status │
├───┼─────┼─────┼────────┤
│   │ A   │ 1   │ 0      │
│   │ A   │ 2   │ 0      │
│   │ A   │ 3   │ 0      │
│   │ A   │ 4   │ 0      │
│   │ A   │ 5   │ 1      │
│   │ B   │ 1   │ 0      │
│   │ B   │ 2   │ 0      │
│   │ B   │ 3   │ 0      │
│   │ B   │ 4   │ 1      │
```

There's definitely an ugly way to do this with some for-loops, but I was wondering if there's a more graceful way to do it, with something like a groupby?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `group_by` on 'uID' and `summarise` to create the columns 'status' and 'day.  With `dplyr` version `>= 1.0`, `summarise` doesn't have the constraint to return only a single row per group

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(uID) %>%
   summarise(status = rep(c(0, 1), c(day-1, 1)), 
           day = seq(day), .groups = 'drop') %>%
   select(names(df1))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 18 x 3
#   uID     day status
#   <chr> <int>  <dbl>
# 1 A         1      0
# 2 A         2      0
# 3 A         3      0
# 4 A         4      0
# 5 A         5      1
# 6 B         1      0
# 7 B         2      0
# 8 B         3      0
# 9 B         4      1
#10 C         1      0
#11 C         2      0
#12 C         3      0
#13 C         4      0
#14 C         5      0
#15 C         6      0
#16 C         7      0
#17 C         8      0
#18 C         9      1
```

---

Or another option is

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(day = map(day, seq)) %>%
    unnest(c(day)) %>%
    group_by(uID) %>%
    mutate(status = +(row_number() == n()))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(uID = c("A", "B", "C"), day = c(5, 4, 9), status = c(1, 
1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: when I run the first solution, I'm getting an error on rep() : invalid times argument

Comment: @wylie can you show your `dplyr` `packageVersion('dplyr')`  I used `>1.0`

Comment: dplyr version 1.0.2

Comment: I also have the same version `packageVersion('dplyr')#
[1] ‘1.0.2’`

Comment: @wylie do you have `plyr` loaded  along with `dplyr`.  Can you try it on a fresh R session

Comment: do not have plyr, only dplyr. just tried with a fresh session and issue persists

Comment: @wylie I am using on R 4.0.3 on a mac.  I tested again and couldn't find any issue on my side

Comment: lol, I'm using a mac and 4.0.3 as well. I'll keep looking into it

Comment: @wylie Not clear why there is a discrepancy in the same version function behavior

Comment: @wylie Is this error on the same data or different? i..e on the data in my post or a different data

Comment: I just tested your solution with the toy 3-row data example I gave, and it worked. It must be an issue with my larger more complex dataset. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @wylie can you check for `NA` values in your data i.e. `colSums(is.na(df1))`

Comment: zero NAs in all columns

Comment: @wylie any value of 0 in 'day' column

Comment: @wylie If I change the value of 'day' to `df1$day[2] <- 0`, it returns error `Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `status`.
✖ invalid 'times' argument`

Comment: I think I sorted it out - there was a duplicate in the uID. not sure why that appeared as a rep() error, but it seems to have sorted out now

Comment: @wylie in that case you may need `day[1]` in both cases because `seq` is not vectorized

Comment: removing the duplicate did the trick, working now. thank you so much for your help!!